# Boot screen doesnt show ubuntu purple screen again

Tags: boot

I installed my ubuntu  few days ago and everything was great until this morning when i started the computer instead of the ubuntu boot screen (with ubuntu and the dots ) i now get a black back ground with loads of writing moving down ...i want my normal boot screen back help!
its not just a black background it has writings on it ... with green 'ok' starting each line

Comment: Ashom doesn't say he is booting into a black screen. He says it's showing text instead of the Ubuntu bootsplash. @Ashom Can you still login after the text-scrolling is done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: So, can you still log in to your user profile? What's the content of `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Try pressing F8.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It's not a duplicate, it seems to boot, but it shows the text scrolling...

Answer (score 1):

You just see kernel starting messages, it's ok. But if you don't want to see them, first open your terminal and enter:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

This will open the text editor, search for a line looking like this:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="....."`

If there isn't any `quiet splash` where I write `.....`, add `quiet splash` between those quotes. There may be other options, don't delete them, you may corrupt your bootloader.

Them close the text editor and enter

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart the computer too see the effects and done.